# numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError csr_matrix toarray()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory, tfidfvectorizer

For my Deep Learning preprocessing, I need to get the terms of frequency of each label.
Each label has already be cleaned (stopwords, punctuation, etc.)
So I used [TfidfVectorizer](https://medium.com/@cmukesh8688/tf-idf-vectorizer-scikit-learn-dbc0244a911a) to get the terms of frequency of each label.
The `fit_transform` function of TfidfVectorizer returns `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`.
And next, I need to convert it to a numpy array with `toarray()` method (to concatenate with my others features).

Code to reproduce:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd


def get_preprocessed_labels_count(data):
    """This function get the preprocessed labels.

    Args:
        data (pd.DataFrame): dataframe with the preprocessed data

    Returns:
        pd.DataFrame: dataframe with the preprocessed labels
    """
    labels = data["Labels"].values
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2))
    labels_count_np = vectorizer.fit_transform(labels)
    labels_count_np = labels_count_np.toarray()
    return labels_count_np


data = pd.DataFrame({"Labels": ["this is a test", "of course now it is working",
                                "but when there are lot of data, there is memory error"]})
print(get_preprocessed_labels_count(data))
```

The problem is that `toarray()` throws an error when converting too much data.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 114, in main
    train_and_test(config)
  File "/storage/simple/projects/train.py", line 676, in train_and_test
    data = get_processed_data(config)
  File "/storage/simple/projects/train.py", line 60, in get_processed_data
    data["Labels_Count"] = get_preprocessed_labels_count(data)
  File "/storage/simple/projects/process_data.py", line 175, in get_preprocessed_labels_count
    labels_count_np = labels_count_np.toarray().tolist()
  File "/home/juana/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/_compressed.py", line 1051, in toarray
    out = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)
  File "/home/juana/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/_base.py", line 1288, in _process_toarray_args
    return np.zeros(self.shape, dtype=self.dtype, order=order)
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate N GiB for an array with shape (x, y) and data type float64
```

For example, with x = 70898 and y = 352302, I have N = 186. GiB of memory (error).
I tried methods to reduce the memory consumption, but it did not work (reducing size of array with asformat(), computing in calc server with 128GB RAM, etc.).

Does it exist a way maybe to keep csr_matrix and concatenate with numpy without converting to numpy array?
Is there a better way to convert ?
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: full traceback please

Comment: @hpaulj I edited with my traceback

Comment: It's the `toarray()` method that's giving the problem.  A (70898,352302) shaped array takes up too much memory.  It fits as csr because it's mostly 0s.  You can't concatenate it to another dense array without this conversion.  There are `sparse.vstack` and `hstack` that can join sparse matrices, making a new sparse matrix.